# Django: sorting by calculated criteria (advance case)

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time_categoty = models.IntegerField()
    importance = models.IntegerField()

class Interaction(models.Model):
    i_date = models.DateTimeField()

class Interaction_customer(models.Model):
    interaction = models.ForeignKey(Interaction)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

Assume:

```
c = Customer.objects.get(pk=1)
x = Interaction.objects.filter(interaction_person__person=c).latest('i_date').i_date
```

(i.e. the latest interaction for given customer)

Is needed: **List of all customers, sorted by criteria:
 time_category/( datetime.now() - x) * c.importance**

Please, don't give me a link to 'extra' on djangoproject.com, I've read it carefully, but really dont know how to implement it in my case. (case is hard, a week nobody can help, django-Jedi is wanted)
Any constructive ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks! //Ed

Comment: sorry, interaction_person__person == interaction_customer__customer

Comment: 1. It's probably best to save that calculation somewhere, for easy sorting (there's no other clear cut way to do that without giving up some efficiency) 2. Your models look like a [ManyToMany with a 'through'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). I don't know if this is what you meant by 'extra', and I entirely don't understand what you need Interaction_Customer for if it doesn't add any other field of its own. Better to just link them directly

Comment: I've deleted all fields, which don't relate to the case, but real base requires just such a structure. //Ed

Comment: Is there any objection to using ManyToMany with 'through'? seems like the design you're looking for

Comment: @yuvi, it is M-to-M relations, but I need to have additional information in connecting-table(I've deleted additional information to simplify example), so I created it by hand and linked by two foreign keys

Comment: Yeah, exactly. That's what 'through' is for. See my answer for detailed implementation. It just makes it easier to connect between them directly

Comment: See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a ManyToMany relationship with a third model for extra data. By linking them, you get the added bonus of an api to connect them directly (which seems like a necessity). Now as for the problem at hand - lets start by creating a method for customer to calculate that data:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time_category = models.IntegerField()
    importance = models.IntegerField()
    interactions = models.ManyToManyField('Interaction', through='InteractionCustomer')

    def delta(self):
        ia = self.interactions.latest('i_date').i_date
        return self.time_categoty / ( datetime.now() - ia ) * self.importance

class Interaction(models.Model):
    i_date = models.DateTimeField()

class InteractionCustomer(models.Model):
    interaction = models.ForeignKey(Interaction)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

Now we want to sort by it. You can do it with python:

```
 sorted( Customer.objects.all(), key=lambda x: x.delta() )
```

or, for efficiency, you can save it to another field. Though in that case, you'll need to update it constantly. You can override save method, but that will only apply when saving the Customer object at hand, which might not always be the case (so you need to think carefully when implementing it this way):

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    ....
    delta = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.delta = self.calc_delta()
        super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your professionalism and willingness to help! The method is easy to implement and it works fine!

Comment: Sure thing! Happy to have helped out =]